# Python convert list to JSON then back to list

Tags: python, json, django

I have created a list that I would like to pass as a JSON string and then convert back to a list.  So my list starts something like this:

```
myList = "[{'Approver': 'demouser', 'name': 'Demo User', 'amount': 100}, {'Approver': 'demouser2', name: 'Demo User 2', 'amount': 200}]"
```

I attempted to convert to JSON:

```
JSONList = json.dumps(myList)
```

I then retrieve this and attempt to convert back to a list by:

```
JSONRetrieve = json.loads(JSONList)
```

What I would like to do at this point is print the amount of each list item:

```
for item in JSONRetrieve:
    print item['amount']
```

However, it is not being recognized as a list or dictionary so I cannot access in this way... any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `myList` is a string. `dumps` expect for example a dict. You need to either create a dict, or load your json string into a dict using `json.load` or something

Comment: In `myList` you don't have a list, you have a string instead. Remove the ' " " ': `[{'Approver': 'demouser', 'name': 'Demo User', 'amount': 100}, {'Approver': 'demouser2', name: 'Demo User 2', 'amount': 200}]`

Comment: Why the double conversion?

Comment: `myList` is a Python string, containing Python literal syntax. It is **not** a list. Start with an actual list. Perhaps you were looking for `import ast; for item in ast.literal_eval(myList): print item['amount']`?

Comment: yes, this ast.literal_eval is exactly what I was looking for.  thank you... if you answer, i will accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a list; you have a *string*. The contents do look like Python literal syntax, you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to turn that into a Python object:

```
import ast
actual_list = ast.literal_eval(myList)
```